# How to change the campaign completion point?

Tags: supreme-commander-2

I had to rebuild my game machine a month or two ago.  When I reloaded Steam and reinstalled Supreme Commander 2, my campaign status was reset back to the first mission.  I don't want to replay all of the missions.  How do I fix the status to be back to mission 12 or whatever one I had completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current status of the campaign is stored in the `Game.prefs` file.
It is located in `$USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Gas Powered Games\Supreme Commander 2\`

**Before doing this, make a copy of that Game.prefs file and save it somewhere.** Just in case you screw it up, you can replace the screw up with the old copy.

If have played any of the campaign missions and either completed one or failed at it, not if you quit playing it, your Game.prefs file will have a 'campaign = { }' section in the profiles block.  Just search for it.

It'll likely look like:

```
        campaign = {
            UEF = {
                SC2_CA_U01 = {...
                }
            }
        }
```

To complete all of the UEF campaign missions:

1. Just copy the entire SC2_CA_U01={ } block.
2. Then paste it right after that }, putting a comma between them.
3. Remove the `completedObjectives` list from that copied block, but leave that `completedObjectives` block itself there.
4. Change the SC2_CA_U01 to SC2_CA_U02. (or a number from 1 to 6)
5. Repeat for each of the 6 UEF missions.

To complete all of the Illuminate missions (starting with a completed UEF missions block):

1. Find the end of the `UEF={` block.
2. Put a comma after it.
3. Paste a copy of the entire UEF block after the comma.
4. Change `UEF` to `Illuminate`.
5. Change all `SC2_CA_U0x` to `SC2_CA_I0x` where x is the mission number.
6. Make sure all `completedObjectives` lists are empty.

I haven't tried to do the Cybran missions yet, but I suspect following the Illuminate instructions but replacing SC2_CA_I0x with SC2_CA_C0x and replacing Illuminate with Cybran might work.  To know for sure, just play the first Cybran mission.  Once you complete it, the Game.prefs file will contain the keys you need.

You can do this in baby steps.  After making a small change, reload the game and see if the campaign menu allows you to select newer missions.  If it didn't work, either the game will make a copy of the Game.prefs file and name it Game.prefs.bad and make a new blank one or it will just ignore the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you no have old files of the game is impossible to recover your game.

The only thing I can think of is that you download a file using the game 100% and continue from where you were going.

http://grandtheftauto.filefront.com/file/100_Complete_Save_Game;43034

Comment: I have save games but the problem is that at least one of the last patches makes the save games unreadable.

Comment: oh, sorry.  I didn't realize you were suggesting that I load a completed game from someone else.

Comment: Your link is for a completely unrelated game.